# Spring statemachine how to persist a machine with nested regions

Tags: spring, spring-boot, state-machine, spring-statemachine

I have statemachine with configuration mentioned at the end, which i want to persist in the database. I am following this tutorial https://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/3.1.0/reference/#statemachine-examples-datajpamultipersist to persist it.

However, when my statemachine is in PARALLEL_TASKS state then i see only one row in database

[image]

is it not suppose to show 3 rows (1 for parent state PARALLEL_TASKS and 2 for sub-states UNLOCKING_EXCESSIVE_POINTS_STARTED, PROCESSING_PAYMENT_STARTED)?

Can someone please tell me how can i fix it? what is wrong with my configuration?

```
@Configuration
@EnableStateMachineFactory(name = "SampleConfig")
@Qualifier("SampleConfig")
public class SampleConfig extends EnumStateMachineConfigurerAdapter<OrderState, OrderEvent> {

    @Autowired
    private JpaPersistingStateMachineInterceptor<OrderState, OrderEvent, String> persister;

    @Override
    public void configure(StateMachineStateConfigurer<OrderState, OrderEvent> states) throws Exception {
        states
                .withStates()
                .initial(OrderState.ORDER_CREATED)
                .state(OrderState.ORDER_CREATED)
                .state(OrderState.PARALLEL_TASKS)
                .end(OrderState.ORDER_COMPLETED)
                .and()
                .withStates()
                .parent(OrderState.PARALLEL_TASKS)
                .region("R1")
                .initial(OrderState.UNLOCKING_EXCESSIVE_POINTS_STARTED)
                .state(OrderState.UNLOCKING_EXCESSIVE_POINTS_STARTED)
                .state(OrderState.UNLOCKED_EXCESSIVE_POINTS)
                .and()
                .withStates()
                .parent(OrderState.PARALLEL_TASKS)
                .region("R2")
                .initial(OrderState.PROCESSING_PAYMENT_STARTED)
                .state(OrderState.PROCESSING_PAYMENT_STARTED)
                .state(OrderState.PROCESSED_PAYMENT)
        ;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(StateMachineTransitionConfigurer<OrderState, OrderEvent> transitions) throws Exception {
        transitions
                .withExternal()
                .source(OrderState.ORDER_CREATED)
                .target(OrderState.PARALLEL_TASKS)
                .event(OrderEvent.ORDER_SUBMITTED_EVENT)
                .and()
                .withExternal()
                .source(OrderState.UNLOCKING_EXCESSIVE_POINTS_STARTED)
                .target(OrderState.UNLOCKED_EXCESSIVE_POINTS)
                .event(OrderEvent.UNLOCKED_POINTS_SUCCESS)
                .and()
                .withExternal()
                .source(OrderState.PROCESSING_PAYMENT_STARTED)
                .target(OrderState.PROCESSED_PAYMENT)
                .event(OrderEvent.PAYMENT_PROCESSED_SUCCESS);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(StateMachineConfigurationConfigurer<OrderState, OrderEvent> config) throws Exception {


        config.withConfiguration()
                .autoStartup(false)
                .regionExecutionPolicy(RegionExecutionPolicy.PARALLEL)
                .and()
                .withPersistence()
                .runtimePersister(persister)
        ;
    }


}
```

Comment: I'm not sure you should see 3 instances of state machine in DB. IMO it should be a single instance that is in a nested composite state and not 3 sequential machines one in each state

Comment: @DanielVilas-Boas: Thanks for replying, atleast someone from community tried helping. I agree it should be single instance but the below documentation is confusing me and if there will be only one record then how state machine will track multiple child records which can be running in parallel https://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/3.1.0/reference/#statemachine-examples-datajpamultipersist

Comment: I was not aware of such scenario. I took a quick look and it really seems that multiple machines should be created in the DB! Have you tried searching the configuration json "datajpamultipersist.json" (should be in the project official repo) that is used in the example to reverse engineer what the configuration looks like? Maybe there is some missconfiguration in your adapter class?

Comment: Did you try setting `machineId`?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I really don't like to say this because I am big fan of Spring State Machine but to tell you the truth persistence is not one of its big fortes, it is most of the time giving me the feeling, it is done to be able to say 'look we have persistence capablities'.

State Machines can be quite complex (look to the UML Specification) and I don't believe persistance layer is designed to deal with all of these complexities.

If you are using Spring State Machine for modelling Shopping Charts, Booking, etc let me ask what would be your (Spring State Machine's) strategy when your business case evolves, what happens when you have to restore a State Machine persisted with the previous release and in this release your business evolved and you have complete different State Machine design.

I found the following framework does much better with above mentioned problems, [Akka Finite State Machine](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/fsm.html) with it's [Event / Schema Evolution](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/persistence-schema-evolution.html) capabilities. It has also a separate [Persistance](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/persistence.html) layer that you have much better control so you will not suffer scenarios as you mentioned above.

Now what you describe above seems like a bug in Spring State Machine and you might get a fix for it, but I strongly advice you to check Akka Framework before you invest more your project resource to Spring State Machine, Spring State Machine is awesome for some problems but not for everything.

Now when you read the Akka Documentation, you will see that it is written in Scala and it is more natural to program your State Machine with Scala (it is possible to program with Java but it gets too clumsy ), if you are reluctant to program in Scala, it is possible to program it as Scala / Java hybrid as I demonstrated in these blogs [blog1](https://mehmetsalgar.wordpress.com/2022/05/17/model-driven-akka-finite-state-machine-fsm/), [blog2](https://mehmetsalgar.wordpress.com/2022/04/18/a-model-driven-event-sourced-cloud-ready-application-with-akka-finite-state-machine-using-kafka-cassandra-and-elasticsearch/).

Event / Schema Evolution capabilities is also demonstrated in the following [blog3](https://mehmetsalgar.wordpress.com/2022/05/17/event-schema-evolution-for-akka-finite-state-machine-fsm/).

I know this is not answer for what you are asking but as a developer probably walk the same road as you, I like to give a fair warning.